# jQuery .each not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone

I have this code in my site that works fine in desktop, but on mobile (specifically an iPhone 6s), it doesn't work at all. I've tried including it in the head and in the footer.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.cat-title').each(function(){
    // caching the variable:
    let el = jQuery(this);
    el.prependTo(el.next('a'));
  });

});
</script>
```

How can I get this to work on mobile?

Comment: what happens if you use `var el = jQuery(this);` instead?

Comment: `'let` is an ES2015 keyword, and is not yet supported in many browsers

Comment: @yts Got it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

some browsers does not supported "let" variables: https://caniuse.com/#search=let